When I perform spring-boot unit testing, the spring datasource is repeatedly initialized
I'm using Groovy + Spock to perform unit testing for a Spring-boot project. I have two test classes, Test Class A and Test Class B. These two test classes are independent and have no dependency relationship. When I run Test Class A or Test Class B individually, the tests pass. However, when I run both test classes together (Test Class A runs first), Test Class B fails, and the exception is as follows:
bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [sql/dml/03-data_table_conf.sql]: INSERT INTO data_table_conf (table_code, dwh_original_table, create_timestamp, update_timestamp, create_user_id, update_user_id) VALUES ('UNIT_TEST_TABLE1', 'rep_aml_acct_ss_d', 1672457674869, 1672457674869, 'system', 'system'), ('UNIT_TEST_TABLE2', 'rep_aml_address_ss_d', 1672457674869, 1672457674869, 'system', 'system'), ('UNIT_TEST_TABLE3', 'rep_aml_address_ss_d', 1672457674869, 1672457674869, 'system', 'system'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "public.uk_table_code_INDEX_9 ON public.data_table_conf(table_code NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 1 */ 'UNIT_TEST_TABLE1' )"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO data_table_conf (table_code, dwh_original_table, create_timestamp, update_timestamp, create_user_id, update_user_id) VALUES ('UNIT_TEST_TABLE1', 'rep_aml_acct_ss_d', 1672457674869, 1672457674869, 'system', 'system'), ('UNIT_TEST_TABLE2', 'rep_aml_address_ss_d', 1672457674869, 1672457674869, 'system', 'system'), ('UNIT_TEST_TABLE3', 'rep_aml_address_ss_d', 1672457674869, 1672457674869, 'system', 'system') [23505-204]

It seems that the sql/dml/03-data_table_conf.sql file configured under spring.datasource.data is repeatedly executed. My Test application.xml file is as follows:
spring:
  datasource:
    data:
      - classpath:sql/dml/03-data_table_conf.sql

My Test Class A is like this:
class SdicReportControllerTest extends ReportingBaseTest {
   //some code
}

My Test Class B is like this:
class SdicReportControllerTest extends ReportingBaseTest {
   @SpringSpy
   AdminPortalService adminPortalService
  
   def setup() {
       adminPortalService.getUserRoles("xxx") >> Collections.singletonList("R200")
   }   
   //some code
}

And ReportingBaseTest is like this:
@SpringBootTest(classes = ReportingPortalApplication.class)
class ReportingBaseTest extends Specification {
   //some code
}

Ironically, when I changed my test classes to be like this（Deleted @SpringSpy）, they passed the tests again.
 class SdicReportControllerTest extends ReportingBaseTest {
   //@SpringSpy
   //AdminPortalService adminPortalService
  
   //def setup() {
   //    adminPortalService.getUserRoles("xxx") >> Collections.singletonList("R200")
   //}   
   //some code
}

Why?
How should I properly use @SpringSpy? In the actual scenario, we need to Spy AdminPortalService.

You could rewrite you init script to be idempotent, e.g., create table if not exists and ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING.
